# Application Domain of Go Language

Tags: programming-languages, go

Can anybody tell me application domain of "go" language ?

Which applications were built using "Go" language ?

For what kind of applications it is best suited for ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html):

> **What is the purpose of the project?**
>
> [...]
> By its design, Go proposes an approach for the construction of system software on multicore machines.
>
> **Is Google using Go internally?**
>
> The Go project was conceived to make it easier to write the kind of servers and other software Google uses internally, but the implementation isn't quite mature enough yet for large-scale production use. While we continue development we are also doing experiments with the language as a candidate server environment. It's getting there. For instance, the server behind http://golang.org is a Go program; in fact it's just the godoc document server running in a production configuration.

So the intended domain is systems and server development for current multicore machines.